# Why `event.preventDefault()` is not working for two nested divs?

Tags: javascript, html, events

```js
function clickOut(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert('click on out');
}

function clickIn(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  alert('click on in');
}
```

```css
#out {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#in {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="out" onclick="clickOut(event)">
  <div id="in" onclick="clickIn(event)">
  </div>
</div>
```

Live demo: http://jsbin.com/qomuteyoke/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Why when I click on the inner div, there still pops two alerts, even if I've called `event.preventDefault()`? First is `click on in`, and 2nd is `click on out`?

Comment: It stops the default action from taking place (this is important for anchors), but doesn't stop the event propagation (bubbling).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `event.stopPropagation()`:

**jQuery def:**

> Description: Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree,
>   preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

**MDN def:**

> Prevents further propagation of the current event.

```
function clickIn(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert('click on in');
}
```

Comment: The description you've mentioned comes from jQuery documentation; perhaps you would want to consider [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) instead :)

Comment: Yeah, I'll add it to the post.

Answer (score 4):

It's because there is no default action to prevent. Prevent default will work on anchor tags, which are used to prevent the default behaviour. What you want to do is to stop the propagation of the click, so it doesn't bubble up from the inner div. That way, if you click on the inner div, only the inner div click fires.

Replace your `event.preventDefault()` with  `event.stopPropagation()`.

Answer (score 2):

Prevent default does not stop the event from propagating to the parents. You want to use `event.stopPropagation();` which prevents further propagation of the current event. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

```js
function clickOut(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  alert('click on out');
}

function clickIn(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  alert('click on in');
}
```

```css
#out {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;

}

#in {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;

}
```

```html
<div id="out" onclick="clickOut(event)">
    <div id="in" onclick="clickIn(event)">          
    </div>
</div>
css
```